# Copying arrays: loops vs. array operations

Tags: arrays, fortran

I work with Fortran now quite a long time but I have a question to which I can't find a satisfying answer.
If I have two arrays and I want to copy one into the other:

```
real,dimension(0:100,0:100) :: array1,array2
...
do i=0,100
   do j=0,100
      array1(i,j) = array2(i,j)
   enddo
enddo
```

But I also noticed that it works as well if I do it like that:

```
real,dimension(0:100,0:100) :: array1,array2
...
array1 = array2
```

And there is a huge difference in computational time! (The second one is much faster!)
If I do it without a loop can there be a problem because I don't know maybe I'm not coping the content just the memory reference?
Does it change anything if I do another mathematical step like:

```
array1 = array2*5
```

Is there a problem on a different architecture (cluster server) or on a different compiler (gfortran, ifort)?

I have to perform various computational steps on huge amounts of data so the computational time is an issue.

Comment: With question asking about performance you should always include the version of the compiler you use and all compilation flags you use, in particular the level of compiler optimizations. There is no single "Fortran" when it comes to performance, Fortran is just a standard for a programming language and can be slow or fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything that @Alexander_Vogt said, but also:

```
do i=0,100
    do j=0,100
        array1(i,j) = array2(i,j)
    enddo
enddo
```

will always be slower than

```
do j=0,100
    do i=0,100
        array1(i,j) = array2(i,j)
    enddo
enddo
```

(Unless the compiler notices it and reorders the loops.)

In Fortran, the first parameter is the fastest changing. That means that in the second loop, the compiler can load several elements of the array in one big swoop in the lower level caches to do operations on.

If you have multidimensional loops, always have the innermost loop loop over the first index, and so on. (If possible in any way.)

Comment: This is the real problem, otherwise the array assignment should not be significantly faster than a DO loop. Whether or not the compiler reorders the loop depends on the optimization level used and the OP does not report it.

Comment: Thanks that's all I wanted to know!

Comment: @ChristophIrrenfried Consider the accepting the answer, we use it here instead of thanking in comments http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Fortran is very capable of performing vector operations. Both

```
array1 = array2
```

and

```
array1 = array2*5
```

are valid operations. 
This notation allows the compiler to efficiently parallelize (and/or) optimize the code, as no dependence on the order of the operations exists.

However, these construct are equivalent to the explicit loops, and it depends on the compiler which one will be faster.

Whether the memory will be copied or not depends on what further is done with the arrays and whether the compiler can optimize that. If there is no performance gain, it is safe to assume the array will be copied.